# Validate Google Wallet JSON

Tags: google-wallet

Before going deeper into coding it, I'm trying to create a valid Google Wallet JSON "by hand", but it seems that Google's own example doesn't pass their own validation tool, or I must be missing something obvious.

Here's what I did:

### Step 1: Create a test account in https://wallet-lab-tools.web.app/issuers

And create a Pass Class along the way. I used my personal Gmail, which has Owner level in my Google Cloud Project.

> FYI: I also created a "proper" account at https://pay.google.com/business/console/profiles, but let's focus on the test account. The proper account doesn't work either :)

[image: Test account in Google Wallet]

### Step 2: Create a Pass Object in https://developers.google.com/wallet/generic/resources/pass-builder

And set the `Card title` and `Header` to `My Title` and `My Name` respectively (because they're empty).

[image: Pass Object in Pass Builder]

### Step 3: Get the JWT

I clicked the "See JWT" link from the screenshot above and copied the `PAYLOAD` part from jwt.io (screenshot below). Obviously, I changed `iss` from `issuer@example.com` to my personal Gmail, which I used when creating the test account, and updated the `classId` to `3388000000022332314.0012707f-37ef-4ad7-9fe9-374a046e921b` (see screenshot in **Step 1**) and `id` to `3388000000022332314.OBJECT1`.

[image: JWT]

### Step 4: Validate the JWT in https://pay.google.com/business/console/passes/BCR2DN4TQHTJFZQ3/issuer/3388000000022332314

Which is the test account dashboard. I pasted the edited JWT into the validation form and clicked "Validate".

What I get: **Failed to verify:An error occurred.**

The error message is very vague. What do I miss?

[image: Validate Google Wallet JWT]